# Truly live streaming to Android/iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, windows, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have spent quite a while (past week) trying this to little avail. However, what I want seems completely unheard of. So far, I have reviewed recommendations available through google, which include encoding a static file into multiple static files in different formats, creating a playlist that hosts static files in an m3u8 file (files which get added to the playlist as streaming continues).
I have also seen ideas involving rtmp, rtsp etc which are completely out of the question because of their incompatibility. 
Ideally, I would have one webpage that would link to the stream (http://server/video.mp4) and/or show it in a webpage (via the video tag). With that in mind, the most likely format would be h264+aac in mp4 container.

Unfortunately, (and probably because the file has no duration metadata) it does not work. I can use a desktop player (such as VLC) to open the stream and play it, but my iPhone and Android both give their respective "Can't be played" messages.

I don't think the problem is caused by the devices' ability to stream, for I have made a streaming shoutcast server work just fine (mp3 only).

Currently, the closest I have become is using the following setup on my win32 machine:

FFMPEG Command:: ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech Webcam 200":audio="Microphone (Webcam 200)" -b:v 180k -bt 240k -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -profile:v baseline -preset ultrafast -r 10 -strict -2 -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 32k -f flv "udp://127.0.0.1:1234"

VLC:: Stream from udp://127.0.0.1:1234 to http:// :8080/video.mp4 (No Transcoding), basically just to convert the UDP stream into an http-accessible stream.

Any hints or suggestions would be warmly welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i'm trying to understand your question.
It seems your trying to play mp4 on both android and iphone from your server via http right?

Do you have a streaming server? Or are you simply trying to have the phone pull the file from your server.

If you don't have one, I suggest checking out darwin streaming server (http://justdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/video-streaming-with-android-phone.html).
It will allow you to set up your video to stream with the right encodings needed for each device.

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Basically, I have a live (continuous) stream that I want to play on my mobile device. The problem being, that most solutions depend on the fact that you're "streaming" a static set of files. This is not what I take to mean by streaming.
The main problem is apparently that video files with infinite length (i.e. they won't end because it's a live stream) don't play correctly on any mobile platform.